# How to import easily RDBMS data into HIVE partition tables

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have tables in my RDBMS. Now I have chosen 3rd column of that table as the partition column for my HIVE table.

Now how can I easily import my RDBMS table's data into HIVE table (considering the partition column)?

Comment: Please check link below.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53485068/handle-partition-in-hive-table-while-using-sqoop-import/53551710#53551710

Answer (score 2):

it works only for static partitions.
refer the below sqoop script for more details :

```
sqoop import 
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/prac" 
--username root 
--password cloudera 
--hive-import 
--query "select id,name,ts from student where city='Mumbai' and \$CONDITIONS" 
--hive-table prac.student 
--hive-partition-key city 
--hive-partition-value 'Mumbai'
--target-dir /user/mangesh/sqoop_import/student_temp5 
--split-by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing rdbms into hive may be achieved using sqoop.

Here is relevant info for importing into paritioned tables:

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive

> You can tell a Sqoop job to import data for Hive into a particular partition by specifying the --hive-partition-key and
>   --hive-partition-value arguments. The partition value must be a string. Please see the Hive documentation for more details on
>   partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

For the dynamic partition you can use like

```
sqoop import \  
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/prac" \  
--username root \  
--password cloudera \  
--table <mysql -tablename> \  
--hcatalog-database <hive-databasename> \  
--hcatalog-table <hive-table name> \
```