# Handle Partition in Hive table while using Sqoop import

Tags: hive, sqoop

i have a question on sqoop import utility. I understand we can run a "sqoop import" and get the data from an RDBMS (SQL Server in my case) and directly put it in a hive table (will be created dynamically).

My question is how to create partitions in this hive table if i have to, with the "sqoop import" utility (is it possible?).

After "sqoop import to Hive" is done, i always see a Hive table which is not partitioned. My requirement is to have a partitioned tables on columns x,y,z..

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: I don't think it's possible. What you can do is create a temporary table (without any partitipon), and then load to final hive table with partition.

Comment: Looks like the case to me as well. Will go with some workarounds. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can import data directly to hive table and can create partition table and load it directly using sqoop.
Please find below code:

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://yourservername:1433;databases=EMP" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager \
--username youruserid \
--password yourpassword \
--fields-terminated-by '|' \
--as-textfile  \
--delete-target-dir \
--target-dir 'hdfspathlocation' \
--hive-import \
--hive-overwrite \
--hive-table UDB.EMPLOYEE_PARTITION_TABLE \
--hive-partition-key EMPLOYEE_CITY \
--hive-partition-value  'NOIDA' \
--num-mappers 1 \
--query "select TEST_EMP_ID,TEST_EMP_NAME,TEST_EMP_DEPARTMENT,TEST_EMP_SALARY,TEST_EMP_CITY FROM EMP.dbo.TEST_EMP_TABLE where TEST_EMP_CITY = 'NOIDA' AND \$CONDITIONS";
```

As you can see that this sqoop import will create a partitioned table UDB.EMPLOYEE_PARTITION_TABLE in hive and create a partitioned column as EMPLOYEE_CITY.

this will create a managed table in hive with data in text format.
below is the schema of hive table:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
|         col_name         |       data_type       |        comment        |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
| test_emp_id              | int                   |                       |
| test_emp_name            | string                |                       |
| test_emp_department      | string                |                       |
| test_emp_salary          | int                   |                       |
| test_emp_city            | string                |                       |
| employee_city            | string                |                       |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # Partition Information  | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # col_name               | data_type             | comment               |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| employee_city            | string                |                       |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+

0 2018-11-30 00:01 /hdfspathlocation/udb.db/employee_partition_table/employee_city=NOIDA
```

You need to make sure few things.
your hive-partition-key column name should not be part of your database table when you are using hive-import. else you will get below error.

```
Imported Failed: Partition key TEST_EMP_CITY cannot be a column to import.
```

keep your partition column at the end of your select statement while specifying the query in sqoop import.

```
select TEST_EMP_ID,TEST_EMP_NAME,TEST_EMP_DEPARTMENT,TEST_EMP_SALARY,TEST_EMP_CITY FROM EMP.dbo.TEST_EMP_TABLE where TEST_EMP_CITY = 'NOIDA' AND \$CONDITIONS
```

Let me know if this works for you.